# How to process multiple images at once

Tags: c#, image, tesseract

I'm trying to extract some text from an image using tesseract, and I've noticed if I divide the image to 9 smaller pieces the system is more accurate, so what I'm trying to accomplish is to process all 9 images at once (parallel) and this is the way I wanted to do it:

```
private static int GetImageText(Image src)
{
    string[] words = { words-to-check };
    List<string> found = new();
    string path = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
    try
    {
        using (var engine = new TesseractEngine(path, "eng", EngineMode.LstmOnly))
        {
            Parallel.ForEach(CutUpImage(src), (img) =>
            {
                using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    img.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                    using (var loadedImg = Pix.LoadFromMemory(ms.ToArray()))
                    using (var page = engine.Process(loadedImg))
                    {
                       var c = page.GetText();
                       foreach (var word in words) if (c.Contains(word)) found.Add(word);
                    }
                }
            });
            return found.Count;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

but I'm getting an error `(Only one image can be processed at once. Please make sure you dispose of the page once your finished with it.)`.

So I had to move the `new TesseractEngine` into the loop like this:

```
private static int GetImageText(Image src)
{
    string[] words = { words-to-check };
    List<string> found = new();
    string path = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
    Parallel.ForEach(CutUpImage(src), (img) =>
    {
        using (var engine = new TesseractEngine(path, "eng", EngineMode.LstmOnly))
        {
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                img.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                using (var loadedImg = Pix.LoadFromMemory(ms.ToArray()))
                using (var page = engine.Process(loadedImg))
                {
                    var c = page.GetText();
                    foreach (var word in words) if (c.Contains(word)) found.Add(word);
                }
            }
        }
    });
    return found.Count;
}
```

but then it takes a full minute to finish processing all images.

so my question is how do I make the `new TesseractEngine` work outside the loop, and more generally how do I make this work faster?

Comment: Are you sure the tesseract error message contains a spelling / grammar mistake?

Comment: @Fildor I copy pasted the error... what is the grammer mistake?

Comment: "Your vs you're". If it's really in the engine, that would be worth notifying the devs.

Comment: @Fildor full error message `Message = "One or more errors occurred. (Only one image can be processed at once. Please make sure you dispose of the page once your finished with it.) (Only one image can be processed at once. Please make sure you dispose of the page once your finished with it.) (On...`

Comment: just copied this from VS 2022

Comment: Ok. That's ... interesting. :) But alas.... You say using 9 Engines takes about a minute. Did you happen to measure how much of the time is spent setting up the engine vs actual processing?

Comment: it takes about 1.5 seconds to set up engine which is 1/4 of the time

Comment: Hmm, ... I mean ... OCR _is_ pretty heavy lifting ... I don't know the images, of course... In the end I must say a minute _could_ be reasonable. But with some "if"s.

Answer (score 1):

ok so the solution to my problem is simple... don't use parallel processing!

I switched the `Parallel.ForEach` to a traditional `foreach` (idk why I decided to try parallel processing first...) and it now takes 12 seconds to process them all, this is the code :

```
private static int GetImageText(Image src)
{
    string[] words = { words-to-check };
    List<string> found = new();
    string path = Environment.CurrentDirectory;

    using (var engine = new TesseractEngine(path, "eng", EngineMode.LstmOnly))
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        foreach (var img in CutUpImage(src))
        {
            img.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            using (var loadedImg = Pix.LoadFromMemory(ms.ToArray()))
            using (var page = engine.Process(loadedImg))
            {
                var c = page.GetText();
                foreach (var word in words) if (c.Contains(word)) found.Add(word);
            }
            ms.SetLength(0);
        }
    return found.Count;
}
```

p.s. this is the `CutUpImage` code if someone ever wants to use it...

```
private static Image[] CutUpImage(Image src)
{
    int widthThird = (int)((double)src.Width / 3.0 + 0.5);
    int heightThird = (int)((double)src.Height / 3.0 + 0.5);
    var imgarray = new Image[9];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            var index = i*3+j;
            imgarray[index] = new Bitmap(widthThird, heightThird);
            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(imgarray[index]);
            g.DrawImage(src, new Rectangle(0, 0, widthThird, heightThird),
                new Rectangle(j * widthThird, i * heightThird, widthThird, heightThird), 
                GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

            g.Dispose();
        }
    return imgarray;
}
```